# how can I get buttons and text aligned in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this code in html but I have a problem is that the text is misaligned and the button is using bootstrap to make this page, how could I make the buttons, the image and the button aligned?

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="explora nuestra gama"> <!-- EXPLORA NUESTRA GAMA -->
      <div class="container text-center py-5">
        <h2> EXPLORA NUESTRA GAMA</h2>
        <div class="row py-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4"> <!-- CARRO 1 -->
            <figure> <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="https://i.imgur.com/45aQm0Z.jpg" width="300" height="120" alt="suv"/> </figure>         
            <h3>SUV</h3>
            <p> <a class="btn btn-dark" href="suv.html">Ver más</a></p> 
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4"> <!-- CARRO 2 -->
            <figure> <img class="img-fluid" src="https://imgur.com/sqzKd7t.jpg" width="300" height="120" alt="pasajero"/> </figure>
            <h3>VEHÍCULO DE PASAJEROS</h3>
            <p> <a class="btn btn-dark" href="#">Ver más</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4"><!-- CARRO 3 -->
            <figure> <img class="img.fluid" src="https://imgur.com/RDPnADx.jpg" width="300" height="120" alt="comercial"/> </figure>
            <h3>COMERCIAL</h3>
            <p> <a class="btn btn-dark" href="comercial.html">Ver más</a></p>
              </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col py-4"> <!-- boton y pagina de salida -->
          <p> <a class="btn btn-dark" href="simulador.html">SIMULA TU CUOTA MENSUAL AQUÍ</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `d-flex flex-column-reverse` in bootstrap, and reverse the order of appearance of the elements inside each div. This will make buttons always align together because they are displayed above the bottom of the div.
Run this code below to see:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="explora nuestra gama">
    <!-- EXPLORA NUESTRA GAMA -->
    <div class="container text-center py-5">
      <h2> EXPLORA NUESTRA GAMA</h2>
      <div class="row py-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 d-flex flex-column-reverse">
          <!-- CARRO 1 -->
          <p> <a class="btn btn-dark" href="suv.html">Ver más</a></p>
          <h3>SUV</h3>
          <figure> <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="https://i.imgur.com/45aQm0Z.jpg" width="300" height="120" alt="suv" /> </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 d-flex flex-column-reverse">
          <!-- CARRO 2 -->

          <p> <a class="btn btn-dark" href="#">Ver más</a></p>
          <h3>VEHÍCULO DE PASAJEROS</h3>

          <figure> <img class="img-fluid" src="https://imgur.com/sqzKd7t.jpg" width="300" height="120" alt="pasajero" /> </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 d-flex flex-column-reverse">
          <!-- CARRO 3 -->

          <p> <a class="btn btn-dark" href="comercial.html">Ver más</a></p>
          <h3>COMERCIAL</h3>
          <figure> <img class="img.fluid" src="https://imgur.com/RDPnADx.jpg" width="300" height="120" alt="comercial" /> </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col py-4">
        <!-- boton y pagina de salida -->
        <p> <a class="btn btn-dark" href="simulador.html">SIMULA TU CUOTA MENSUAL AQUÍ</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't align them at all

Comment: @spacemonki yes it does. You need to click on 'Expand snippet' to see fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to have space between the image and the text so the text will always align at the bottom or wherever you want it.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-between">
    <figure>
        <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="https://i.imgur.com/45aQm0Z.jpg" width="300" height="120" alt="suv"/>
    </figure>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <h3>SUV</h3>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-dark" href="suv.html">Ver más</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `class="mb-3"` will be whatever margin you want between the text and the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Within the code:

```
<figure>
  <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="https://i.imgur.com/45aQm0Z.jpg" width="300" height="120" alt="suv" />
</figure>
```

`.figure-img` contains a `margin-bottom: .5rem;` that isn't being applied to the other elements. Remove that or add to the others so they have the same classes applied.